# Is there an orthodox way to avoid compiler warning C4309 - "truncation of constant value" with binary file output?

Tags: c++, file-io, compiler-warnings, binary-data, truncation

My program does the common task of writing binary data to a file, conforming to a certain non-text file format. Since the data I'm writing is not already in existing chunks but instead is put together byte by byte at runtime, I use `std::ostream::put()` instead of `write()`. I assume this is normal procedure.

The program works just fine. It uses both `std::stringstream::put()` and `std::ofstream::put()` with two-digit hex integers as the arguments. But I get compiler warning C4309: "truncation of constant value" (in VC++ 2010) whenever the argument to `put()` is greater than 0x7f. Obviously the compiler is expecting a `signed char`, and the constant is out of range. But I don't think any truncation is actually happening; the byte gets written just like it's supposed to.

Compiler warnings make me think I'm not doing things in the normal, accepted way. The situation I described has to be a common one. *Is there are common way to avoid such a compiler warning*? Or is this an example of a pointless compiler warning that should just be ignored?

I thought of two inelegant ways to avoid it. I could use syntax like `mystream.put( char(0xa4) )` on every call. Or instead of using `std::stringstream` I could use `std::basic_stringstream< unsigned char >`, but I don't think that trick would work with `std::ofstream`, which is not a templated type. I feel like there should be a better solution here, especially since `ofstream` is meant for writing binary files.

Your thoughts?

**--EDIT--**

Ah, I was mistaken about `std::ofstream` not being a templated type. It is actually `std::basic_ofstream<char>`, but I tried that method that and realized it won't work anyway for lack of defined methods and polymorphic incompatibility with `std::ostream`.

Here's a code sample:

```
stringstream ss;
int a, b;
/* Do stuff */
ss.put( 0 );
ss.put( 0x90 | a ); // oddly, no warning here...
ss.put( b );        // ...or here
ss.put( 0xa4 );     // C4309
```

Comment: Just so we're all clear, can you add a concrete code example to your question?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found solution that I'm happy with. It's more elegant than explicitly casting every constant to `unsigned char`. This is what I had:

```
ss.put( 0xa4 ); // C4309
```

I thought that the "truncation" was happening in implicitly casting `unsigned char` to `char`, but Cong Xu pointed out that integer constants are assumed to be signed, and any one greater than 0x7f gets promoted from `char` to `int`. Then it has to actually be truncated (cut down to one byte) if passed to `put()`. By using the suffix "u", I can specify an unsigned integer constant, and if it's no greater than 0xff, it will be an `unsigned char`. This is what I have now, without compiler warnings:

```
ss.put( 0xa4u );
```

Answer (score 7):

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss.put(0x7f);
ss.put(0x80); //C4309
```

As you've guessed, the problem is that `ostream.put()` expects a `char`, but `0x7F` is the maximum value for `char`, and anything greater gets promoted to `int`. You should cast to `unsigned char`, which is as wide as `char` so it'll store anything `char` does and safely, but also make truncation warnings legitimate:

```
ss.put(static_cast<unsigned char>(0x80)); // OK
ss.put(static_cast<unsigned char>(0xFFFF)); //C4309
```

Comment: Why do you use `ss.put(static_cast<unsigned char>(0x80));` instead of `ss.put(unsigned char(0x80))` or `ss.put((unsigned char) 0x80)`? Is a static cast preferred for some reason?

Comment: @SamKauffman, it's just the modern C++ way of doing casts. It's wordier but less ambiguous and safer.

Comment: @CongXu, thanks! What you wrote about promotion helped me understand what truncation is actually going on.

Comment: @SamKauffman `ss.put(unsigned char(0xFFFF));` <--- no warning. That's why C++ casts are preferred over C casts.